# Construct dual network for conversion of min-cut problem to shortest path problem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, network-flow

I was wondering if there is some typo in the following description from Section 8.4 p263 of Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications by Ravindra K. Ahuja, Thomas L. Magnanti, and James B. Orlin.

[image]

> We now show how to transform a minimum
>   cut problem on an s-t planar network (s means source and t means sink)
>   into a shortest path problem. In the
>   given s-t planar network, we first
>   draw a new arc joining the nodes s and
>   t so that the arc stays within the
>   unbounded face of the network [see
>   Figure 8.8(b)]; this construction
>   creates a new face of the network,
>   which we call the additional face, but
>   maintains the network's planarity. We
>   then construct the dual of this
>   network; we designate the node
>   corresponding to the additional face
>   as the dual source s * and the node
>   corresponding to the unbounded face as
>   the dual sink t*. We set the cost of
>   an arc in the dual network equal to
>   the capacity of the corresponding arc
>   in the primal network. The dual
>   network contains the arc (s*, t*)
>   which we delete from the network. Figure 8.8(b) shows this construction: the dashed lines are the arcs in the dual network.

1. How shall I understand the one before the last
   sentence "The dual network contains
   the arc (s*, t*) which we delete
   from the network"? Why I don't see
   an arc between s* and t* in the dual network?
2. Does the dash arc (s, t) constructed
   at the beginning belong to the dual
   network? I guess not, because s and
   t are not vertices in the dual
   graph, isn't it?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The network in (b) shows the situation after deletion of the $(s^*, t^*)$ arc.  The $(s^*, t^*)$ arc needs to be removed in order to have a one-to-one correspondence between $s$-$t$ cuts in the primal and paths from $s^*$ to $t^*$ in the dual.
2. No, it doesn't belong to the dual network.  Dual arcs must be between faces in the primal network.  I'm not sure why they left it in figure (b), as it is a bit confusing to have it there.